# String or byte array to store a large set of Long integers in Redis

Tags: serialization, redis, protocol-buffers

I have a high read traffic(order of 50,000 QPS) gRPC service with Redis database which we connect with Lettuce library. We update Redis from a Kafka topic, where for String keys, we append Long integers to a Redis Set as the data comes in.

When a request is made to the service with a String key, we we want to pull all members of the Set for that key within minimal latency as our service needs to return response in around 10ms. The size of a Set can vary between 100 to 100,000. Between String and byte array encoding, what would be a faster way to fetch these Long integers in terms of faster serialization/deserialization?

Using String: I convert the integers to Strings using `Long.toString` and push them to the Redis set and later use `Long.parseLong` to convert the String back to Long integer.

Using Byte Array: Using protocol buffers(Protobuf), I create a Long int64 Protobuf message. I convert the Long integer to this message, convert it using `toByteArray()` and push it to the Redis set and later for read, parse the byte array to get that message and then the Long integer from it.

Are there any other faster ways, like using Lua script to fetch all Set elements faster?

Comment: question: why is this a "set" in redis? If you're fetching all the values each time, the "set" feature isn't being used in any useful/meaningful way. I wonder if you'd be open to alternative ideas there. For example, instead of a "set", maybe just a "string" that is a dence chunk of the raw bytes; I don't know Java very well, but if this was C#, it would be trivial to "pun"/coerce the data between bytes and longs, such that there is zero deserialization, ever (just: thunking), and this "string" approach would handily minimize redis protocol overheads (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) to answer your Lua question: no, Lua can't do anything that you can't already do better with SMEMBERS.  However, my next question would be *why* are you fetching all the values out each time? Is that actually needed, or is that just "because we are"? If you can leave the data in redis, even better. Alternatively, maybe some caching in your app is called for, such that you don't need to fetch it *each time*. Many many options here, depending on the exact scenario.

Comment: It is a Set due to the write operation. When writing from Kafka data, we can get duplicate elements. One way is that instead of using Set, we can save it as Redis String type consisting of a list of numbers and during writes we fetch the String, convert it to a List, add the number and write back the updated list. However this can result in race condition. We can avoid it by ensuring only one read-->update operation is done at a time, but there is a still a chance.

Comment: Regarding why we are fetching the whole Set, it's because we have to merge multiple such sets and send them as a combined set back to service caller. We have added a local cache in the app but it can only take in a few GBs at best and our Redis database is more than 100 GB so we can't cache everything.

Comment: ok; suggestion: next thing to do is to test "best case", to avoid wasting time. Find the size of a typical big-ish set - let's imagine you choose the size 60000. What we want to do is to create a redis "string" that is 8xN long, so: 480000 bytes. Don't worry about the contents, it could be garbage, it doesn't matter. Now fetch that string with GET (making sure to use a binary API, not a UTF8 API) and compare the time it takes to do SMEMBERS on the similar set. Is it any quicker? This 8xN isn't quite the *smallest* (there are other ways of encoding things), but it is the *most direct*

Comment: If it doesn't make any difference, then: we have an answer, it just isn't a good one. If it is faster, it suggests we can try to do some post-processing here - to convert the sets into strings once we've finished importing, or perhaps to have two versions otherwise - one set (the live data), one string-with-expiry that is a lazily calculated cache snapshot of the processed data: try to get the string first, if it is missing: fetch the set, compute the bytes, store the bytes; this depends a little on whether any staleness is ever OK, but if not: you can also so "SADD+DEL" when importing, i.e.

Comment: every time you have a new set member, delete the pre-computed string if it exists; there *may* even be a fancy way of doing an append in Lua if the SADD reports true, but that sounds hard :) but as I say: the first thing to test is: is a redis "string" of 8xN bytes faster to fetch than a "set" of N members?

Comment: Apparently the conditional append might not be that hard in Lua, if `string.pack("<i8", value)` works - I might take a look later

Answer (score 3):

Redis sets are very powerful for server-side (redis) operations, but if you find yourself frequently fetching all the contents from a set: *something has gone very wrong*. In this case, the set element values are small, which means you will be paying a relatively large amount of protocol overhead, deframe overhead,  parse overhead, etc - just to deal with how redis expresses sequences.

However! Let's imagine we held the N items in a redis set (for the redis unique add capability), but *also* in a redis binary string, of 8xN bytes - just the raw bytes of integers slammed one after the other. We could post-process the sets into the string, or we could use Lua to add the elements, for example:

```lua
if redis.call('SADD', KEYS[1], ARGV[1]) == 1 then
    redis.call('APPEND', KEYS[2], ARGV[2])
    return true
end
return false
```

With the data as a redis string, we can do a single `GET`; this is much simpler than `SMEMBERS` - and we pay virtually no protocol overhead. Equally, the receiving library doesn't have to parse the incoming fragments into a typed array - most libraries have simple primitives for raw byte buffers. If we are *overly* concerned about very large fetches, we could use `SUBSTR` in a loop to read chunks, rather than fetching everything at once. And depending on your platform capabilities: once we have a raw binary buffer, we *might* be able to use "punning" (think "reinterpret cast") rather than any kind of deserialize/parse step, so that we don't have to process the results in any way: *we just take them as we see them*.

Now the question becomes: is this faster? Well, the easiest way to answer such a question is to *test it*, so: let's do that!

I'm not a Java person - I'm a C# head, but we're not testing the platform here - we're trying to answer "could this help?", so: let's not worry about that. Long story short (too late!), the answer is "yes". Here's my benchmark results using 50,000 elements:

```
BenchmarkDotNet v0.13.12, Windows 11 (10.0.26058.1100)
AMD Ryzen 9 5900HS with Radeon Graphics, 1 CPU, 16 logical and 8 physical cores
.NET SDK 8.0.100
  [Host]     : .NET 8.0.0 (8.0.23.53103), X64 RyuJIT AVX2
  DefaultJob : .NET 8.0.0 (8.0.23.53103), X64 RyuJIT AVX2


| Method     | Mean        | Error     | StdDev      | Ratio |
|----------- |------------:|----------:|------------:|------:|
| GetMembers | 36,127.2 us | 720.40 us | 1,596.36 us | 1.000 |
| GetString  |    245.6 us |   1.61 us |     1.50 us | 0.007 |
```

The `SMEMBERS` approach here is *147 times more expensive*.

With a sum test (to check they're seeing the same data):

```
SMEMBERS:       -1885294786466967137
GET:            -1885294786466967137
```

(the numbers will be different each run, but should match each-other)

Finally, here's my entire test suite, in case I've done something obviously wrong:

```cs
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;
using StackExchange.Redis;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

#if DEBUG
// simple test
var obj = new RedisBenchmark();
obj.Init();
Console.WriteLine($"SMEMBERS:\t{obj.GetMembers()}");
Console.WriteLine($"GET:\t\t{obj.GetString()}");
#else
// bench run
BenchmarkRunner.Run<RedisBenchmark>();
#endif

public class RedisBenchmark
{
    private ConnectionMultiplexer muxer = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("127.0.0.1:6379");
    private static RedisKey KeySet = "foo/set", KeyString = "foo/str";
    private IDatabase db;

    [GlobalSetup]
    public void Init()
    {
        if (!BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
        {
            throw new PlatformNotSupportedException("Big-endian path not implemented");
        }

        // reset and load with test data
        db = muxer.GetDatabase();
        db.KeyDelete(KeySet);
        db.KeyDelete(KeyString);
        int count = 50000;
        var rand = new Random();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8];
        ref long punned = ref MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, long>(buffer)[0];
        RedisKey[] keys = [KeySet, KeyString];
        RedisValue[] argv = [0L, buffer];
        while (count > 0)
        {
            var value = rand.NextInt64();
            punned = value; // this actually writes to "buffer", thanks to ref-local

            /*
            // this is the simple version, but this has race conditions; you
            // wouldn't do this in a per-add way, but you might post-process
            // a set to create a string
            if (db.SetAdd(KeySet, value))
            {
                db.StringAppend(KeyString, buffer);
                count--;
            }
            */

            // but the fancy way is to get Lua to do the append, which works
            // in a thread-safe way at the server; we can do this per-add safely;
            // string.pack("<i8", ...) didn't work inside redis, so I'm passing
            // the bytes down, but: that's fine
            argv[0] = value;
            var added = (bool)db.ScriptEvaluate("""
                if redis.call('SADD', KEYS[1], ARGV[1]) == 1 then
                    redis.call('APPEND', KEYS[2], ARGV[2])
                    return true
                end
                return false
                """, keys, argv);

            if (added) count--;
        }
    }


    [Benchmark(Baseline = true)]
    public long GetMembers()
    {
        long sum = 0;
        foreach (var value in db.SetMembers(KeySet))
        {
            sum += (long)value;
        }
        return sum;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public long GetString()
    {
        using var lease = db.StringGetLease(KeyString);
        if (lease is null) return 0;

        var punned = MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, long>(lease.Span);
        long sum = 0;
        foreach (var value in punned)
        {
            sum += value;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

---

I can't guarantee that you'll have the exact same results in Java with Lettuce, but: this is interesting enough to at least make it worth trying to port the experiment to find out.

---

Since you mention gRPC, it is also worth noting that if your schema defines `repeated int64 values = ...` for the values, there is also a sneaky way to present this from a raw buffer using "packed" encoding, so: zero translation again, all the way from redis to gRPC

Answer (score 1):

I would take a step back and try to consider the entire system rather than fixating on serialization/deserialization. What is the *actual bottleneck*? What are you doing at that point? Are you querying individual elements inside redis? (in which case, latency is your likely limit, and you can't change that without changing how everything interconnects) or are you fetching all the values out / inserting bulk values? In that scenario then bandwidth is more likely your limit, but if you're doing that frequently: you probably aren't using the redis "set" as a "set", and other options might be beneficial.

You also don't specify your redis library/usage: if you're doing a large number of operations, "pipelining" is your friend to avoid per-operation latency costs. Without seeing exactly what you're doing, it is hard to know whether you're currently paying this cost, and whether this is in fact: the problem. Even if pipelining isn't available in your client, batching via things like Lua might be - sending 50 (say) elements per round trip can make a huge difference in overall cost (pipelining would be better).

The difference in ASCII vs protobuf vs CPU (fixed width / endianness) encoding *can matter* in some scenarios, but in this specific case: the redis protocol itself has overheads per element that are going to make that moot for these small values (unless those overheads are amortized, for example by encoding multiple values in a single payload).

For context: I am intimately familiar with both redis and protobuf, and work in network comms on a daily basis.

Comment: Thanks Marc. Have updated my question with library used and why we use Redis Sets. The bottleneck is read latency while pulling all elements for a Set and converting them to Long Integers. My question is what is the fastest way to do this operation.